# The use of it as object

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, dummy-pronouns

**[SOURCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/for)**

The following sentence is from the online Longmans dictionary.

> He found it increasingly difficult to read, for his eyes were failing.

Is the part of sentence "it increasingly difficult to read" a noun phrase as an object? I know the sentence is correct but what is the role of "it" and its relation with the following part of the sentence.

Comment: i think this is what Huddleston & Pullum call an _Internal Complement Extraposition_. "It" here is the _dummy "it"_, and that is the object, not the phrase you cite. Have you studied the _dummy "it"_?

Comment: @user178049 See _A Student's Introduction to English_, Huddleston & Pullum, P. 248. This is definitely the dummy it.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Is it only a object or increasingly difficult to read is also a object.?

Comment: The object is just "it". The AdjP "increasingly difficult" is objective predicative complement. The subordinate clause "to read" is extraposed object.

Comment: @BillJ Can you find a direct ref. in CGEL to this formation? I'm looking at p. 1408 in the 2002, and p.960, 4.3.2. Is that it? We extrapose the subordinate clause because _"He found to read it increasingly difficult"_ positions the adjectival phrase (AdjP) apart from the clause it modifies.

Answer (score 1):

The “it” is being used to refer to something (an object) that was referred to earlier. In this sentence, the author is describing the object (it) in more detail than the sentence it originated in as not to create a run on sentence.

Comment: This is a possible meaning, with context (if the book or paper has already been mentioned). Without that context, the _it_ is a dummy object, as mentioned in several comments.